# Will Feeblemind affect all the brains of a creature that has multiple brains?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Feeblemind says that one creature is affected.

Does that means casting that spell on an Ettin, a Hydra, or even the Tiamat would affect all the brains at once?

As a DM, I would argue that it should be per brain, otherwise what good would it bring to a monster to have multiple heads? But it seems the rules clearly say "a creature" as a whole.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Feeblemind reduces Intelligence, and even a creature with multiple brains has only a single Intelligence score. As such, it can only be affected once.

(Save yourself the headache of trying to figure out how to determine spells for a Two-headed Ettin Wizard where one head still has an Int of 16 and the other has an Int of 1 and just make it affect the whole thing)

This is in addition to the RAW argument that yes, an Ettin is a single creature.

Answer (score 11):

> Does that means casting that spell on an Ettin, a Hydra, or even the Tiamat would affect all the brains at once?

Going by the RAW, yes. It targets a creature, not a brain.

> otherwise what good would it bring to a monster to have multiple heads?

Multiple bite attacks, being able to look in multiple directions at once, being able to have amusing and flavourful arguments with itself, …